# Why is ActivationUri null by using Chrome?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, deployment, clickonce

When run the URL "http://localhost/?Id=User1" in IE, the ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query returns "?Id=User1", that's right.

When run the URL "http://localhost/?Id=User1" in Chrome, the ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri is null, why? How solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Deployment;
using System.Deployment.Application;

namespace COSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Network");
                MessageBox.Show(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Local");
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the sorrounding code around the above statement ?

Comment: I added the sample code, thanks.